# Blender 2.8 create mesh via script

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, uv

I need to create a mesh by reading a custom file format.
I have a list of vertices, faces and uvs.

So far I am able to create a mesh with vertices and faces with the following script:

```py
import bpy
import bmesh

# verts = [...]
# uvs = [...]
# faces = [...]

mesh_data = bpy.data.meshes.new("cube_mesh_data")
mesh_data.from_pydata(verts, [], faces)
mesh_data.update()

obj = bpy.data.objects.new("My_Object", mesh_data)

scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.collection.objects.link(obj)
obj.select_set(state=True)
```

However, I cannot find a way to assign the UV array to the vertices. UV is a list of pair of floats with the same length as verts.
I have looked online but couldn't find any solution.

Any tips or resources I could read?
Thank you very much!

Comment: UV coordinates are generally per face/vertex (not only per vertex as a 3D vertex could be used several times in the UV map). Could you describe a bit more the input data?

Comment: You're right, however in this case each vertex is used exactly once. The input data is an xml that is parsed to a list of vertices (list of tuples of 3 floats each), a list of uvs (list of pairs of 2 floats each with same size as the vertices) and a list of faces (tuples of 3 int each)

Comment: OK, so I imagine that 3D vertices are eventually doubled in your case. Anyway, you can set uv coordinates to "o.data.uv_layers['UVMap'].data[x].uv" where "x" is given inside "o.data.polygons[p].loop_indices".